# VSS causing crash in VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crash, visual-sourcesafe-2005

We use Visual Studio 2008, with visual source safe v8. Lately, I seem to be getting a lot more crashes than usual, mainly when viewing history (comparing, etc.).

I have taken a screencapture of the series of dialog boxes that will always appear, leading up to the crash:
http://img529.imageshack.us/img529/1360/msvscrash.jpg

Does anyone know what could be causing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run Analyze against the VSS database?  Database corruption in VSS can happen whenever you get a Visual Studio crash.  Running an analyze, and then probably a repair, might resolve the problem.